# Export data from mysql into text file?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export some data from a mysql table into a text file.

However, I only get a few `,` written into my text file without the actual data in the `members` table!

I am using the code bellow:

```
<?php
    $fh = fopen('email-data.txt', 'w');
    include "../config/connect.php";

    /* insert field values into data.txt */

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){           
        $num = mysqli_num_fields($query) ;    
        $last = $num - 1;
        for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {            
            fwrite($fh, $row[$i]);                       
            if ($i != $last) {
                fwrite($fh, ",");
            }
        }                                                                 
        fwrite($fh, "\n");
    }
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Why aren't you storing the text you want to be written in a variable and do the writing at the end? Only 1 `fwrite`, much easier to debug and modify in the future imo

Comment: you are using `MYSQLI_ASSOC` which should be `MYSQLI_NUM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `MYSQLI_ASSOC` to `MYSQLI_NUM`

You are fetching rows with `Numbers` But using an Assiciative array

Answer (score 0):

something like this? you receive an assoc array, without numeric indices

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('email-data.txt', 'w');
include "../config/connect.php";

/* insert field values into data.txt */

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){           
    //$num = mysqli_num_fields($query) ;    
    //$last = $num - 1;
    //for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {            
    $last = sizeof($row)-1;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($row as $field) {
        fwrite($fh, $field);                       
        if ($i != $last) {
            fwrite($fh, ",");
        }
        $i++;
    }                                                                 
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the second argument of `mysqli_fetch_array()` function.

While loop should look like `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM)){...}`